# Entity Framework DBContext, custom connection string at runtime

Tags: c#, web-config, entity-framework-5

I have a need to specify the connection string of the DBContext at runtime. Do I need to specify the connection string as it exists in web.config (with metadata=res:blah blah)? If so, is there a way it should be done because just pasting in the string as it is in the web config gives a "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'" error. For reference, the connection string is as follows:

```
    <add name="EFEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MHFedmx.csdl|res://*/Models.MHFedmx.ssdl|res://*/Models.MHFedmx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={IP ADDRESS}\;initial catalog={SOME DB};persist security info=True;user id={ID};password={PASSWORD};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Are you using Code first?

Comment: Sorry, model first (edmx from the database to generate the models)

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to share the same connection string with your Identity DbContext?

Comment: As far as I've seen (and I'm not an EF guru by any means), that connection string IS the connection string for the context. I need to specify it at run-time because things like credentials and port numbers need to disappear from the web.config.

Comment: The Identity context is a Code First context, which doesn't use Metadata (or specifically, doesn't use EntityClient).  That's why you're getting the error.  The Identity context is throwing it.  You need a different connection string for your Model First context.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding which is which. The connection string runs just fine when in web.config but throws an error if I try Pit Ming's suggestion. To be clear, I added an EF object to the project, generated from the database (and entered the correct connection details) and it put the string I posted in the web.config. So the metadata is generated by VS. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that I need to not include meta data when I use the specify the string at runtime and use an EF object, correct?

Comment: What i'm saying is that you need separate connection string entries if you're using an EDMX based DbContext with a non-EDMX based context.  If you have a Model First DbContext *AND* and an IdenityContext then this is the case.  EDMX based connection strings need the metadata entries, while Code First based (the Identity Context) does not.

Comment: I already know this. But the number of connection strings ultimately doesn't answer the question (how do I specify the connection string for EF at run-time so that it's not in the web config). The connectino string provided in the question is the one VS generated when I added the EF object to the solution. I need to specify that at run time.

Comment: There are tons of answers to that question already if you had bothered to search.  For instance.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561903/ef-connection-string-as-dbcontext-constructor-argument

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
var ecb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
ecb.Metadata = "res://*/Models.MHFedmx.csdl|res://*/Models.MHFedmx.ssdl|res://*/Models.MHFedmx.msl";
ecb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
ecb.ProviderConnectionString = "data source={IP ADDRESS};initial catalog={SOME DB};persist security info=True;user id={ID};password={PASSWORD};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

ecb.Connectionstring contains the connection string you're looking for.

Comment: Heh, it's still making the same complaint. Your code plus ` db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ecb.ConnectionString;'

And it still complains. Did I miss something on that?

Actually, I want to take the connection string out of web config and replace it with a builder completely but it doesn't like it not being in there so maybe my question should be a bit broader: how to specify a connection string for EF at runtime...