# specify Asp.net LocalSqlServer connection string in code

Tags: asp.net

Normally, we define that connection string in web.config

Is there a way we can specify that connection string in code, like in Application_Start?

That connection string normally used to connect aspnetdb
example:

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: asp.net use that connection string to connect to aspnetdb,  I just want to find a programming way to tell asp.net which database i want to use for the aspnetdb purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you're *not* using entity framework, you can use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Sub Main()
' Create a new DbConnctionStringBuilder, and add items 
' to the internal collection of key/value pairs. 
Dim builder As New DbConnectionStringBuilder()
builder.Add("Data Source", "c:\MyData\MyDb.mdb")
builder.Add("Provider", "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0")
builder.Add("Jet OLEDB:Database Password", "*******")
builder.Add("Jet OLEDB:System Database", _
    "c:\MyData\Workgroup.mdb")
' Set up row-level locking.
builder.Add("Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode", 1)

' Display the contents of the connection string, which 
' will now contain all the key/value pairs delimited with 
' semicolons.
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString)
Console.WriteLine()

' Clear the DbConnectionStringBuilder, and assign a complete 
' connection string to it, to demonstrate how 
' the class parses connection strings.
builder.Clear()
builder.ConnectionString = _
    "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;" & _
    "Integrated Security=SSPI" 

' The DbConnectionStringBuilder class has parsed the contents,  
' so you can work with any individual key/value pair.
builder("Data Source") = "."
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString)
Console.WriteLine()

' Because the DbConnectionStringBuilder class doesn't  
' validate its key/value pairs, you can use this class 
' to store any semicolon-delimited list. The following 
' snippet places an arbitrary string into the ConnectionString 
' property, changes one of the values, and then displays the 
' resulting string.
builder.Clear()
builder.ConnectionString = _
    "Value1=10;Value2=20;Value3=30;Value4=40"
builder("Value2") = 25
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString)
Console.WriteLine()

builder.Clear()
Try 
    ' Assigning an invalid connection string 
    ' throws an ArgumentException.
    builder.ConnectionString = "xxx" 

Catch ex As ArgumentException
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid connection string.")
End Try

Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to finish.")
Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: How to tell asp.net to use that connection string to connect aspnetdb?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework, you can use the Entity ConnectionString builder

```
            internal static EntityConnectionStringBuilder GetConnectionString()
            {
                // Specify the provider name, server and database. 
                string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
                string serverName;
                string databaseName;

                databaseName = "MyDatabase";
                serverName = "localhost";


                // Initialize the connection string builder for the underlying provider.
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
                {
                    // Set the properties for the data source.
                    DataSource = serverName,
                    InitialCatalog = databaseName,
                    IntegratedSecurity = false,

                    UserID = "sqluser",
                    Password = "password",
                };

                // Build the SqlConnection connection string. 
                string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

                // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
                EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder()
                {
                    //Set the provider name.
                    Provider = providerName,

                    // Set the provider-specific connection string.
                    ProviderConnectionString = providerString,

                    // Set the Metadata location.
                    Metadata = "@ENTER META DATA HERE"
                };

                return entityBuilder;
            }
        }
```

You can then add a constructor to your entity to accept a connection string (borrowed from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16930334/3033053))

```
public partial class MyEFEntities
{
    public MyEFEntities(string connectionstring)
        : base(connectionstring)
    {
    }
}
```

Finally, you can call it like this:

```
using (var connection = DAL.MyEFEntities(GetConnectionString().ToString()))
{
   // Do work here
}
```

Comment: if not, then possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, I don't know how off the top of my head.  I'd suggest updating your question to include the specific type of database connection you're using.  See Dura's answer